# How to create Vue component with exportable function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I am trying to understand how to create components with exportable functions.
For example: i want to create message box, that will appear on screen when in some other component i call method showMessage() imported from this component.
In message box component i want to describe logic and template.
How to reach this? Very appreciate any docs/articles about this, if any.

Comment: Exporting is not a correct term. You need to call a method on the instance of some component, and this is done by accessing a ref. https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html

Comment: You could make the component and its methods global.  Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473778/call-global-components-method-from-another-view-component-in-vue-js-3

Comment: I don’t think you need to call a method for that in the component. Look into how props and emits work in Vue. https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#props  https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html

Comment: Thank you! I will learn all the links. Gabe, i know about props/events, but main goal i want to reach - is not to include this component in every template where i need it, i want to directly call it from the code. Good example is Message from Element Plus, it is calling just as a function, but there is one minus that i need to specify target to which message is must be mounted. I'd prefer just a message with maximal z-index. I know that i can find and use other libraries, but i want to get understanding of how it works by implementing this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. mount your message component in App.vue (or in other global file),
2. control its props with function in store

like

```
<MyMessage :value="isOpen" :title="title" :message="message" />

...
<script setup>
...
const isOpen = reactive(piniaStore().message.isOpen);
const title = computed (() => piniaStore().message.title);
...
</script>
```

```
// store
const message = reactive({{});

// do reactive things..
const showMessage(title, _message) => {
   message.title = title;
   message.message = _message;
   message.isOpen = true;
}
...
```

then you can call the message with piniaStore().showMessage(...) wherever you want

(this code is a concept, you have to develop if you want to run properly..)

---

but i think you can use [Quasar framework - Dialog](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/dialog#introduction) ($q.dialog is exactly what you need!)
or [Ionic framework - alert](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert),  [Vuetify - dialog api](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-alert/) etc (every framework has these things)